# How to get the correct elements with elementbyid? simple correction or input should solve the failure

Tags: javascript, php, css, block, displayobject

What simple step is on this javascript, php, display failure missing? can't figure it out

The code is this:

```
 <?php $countrycode=$p["country"]; ?>
    <select size="1" name="countrycode" id="countrycode" onchange="javascript:
        if(this.value=='USA') { 
            document.getElementById('us').style.display='block';
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('us').style.display='none';
        } 
        if(this.value=='DE') {
            document.getElementById('de').style.display='block';
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('de').style.display='none';
        }
    ">
        <option value="INT" <?php 
            if($countrycode=='INT') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
        >International</option>
        <option value="USA" <?php
            if($countrycode=='USA') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
        >USA</option>
        <option value="DE" <?php
            if($countrycode=='DE') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> 
        >DE</option>
    </select>
```

This is the echo (elementid ++):

in php (open php tag as: 'php' - for better reading):

```
php if($countrycode=='USA') { echo 'display:block;'; } else { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>" id="us"><br />Also allow: 
                <input type="checkbox" id="Targeting_CA" name="Targeting_CA" 

php if($p["CA"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="1">&nbsp;Canada
                &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="Targeting_UK" name="Targeting_UK" 

php if($p["UK"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="1">&nbsp;United Kingdom
                &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="Targeting_AU" name="Targeting_AU" 

php if($p["AU"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>  value="1">&nbsp;Australia


php if($countrycode=='DE') { echo 'display:block;'; } else { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>" id="de"><br />Also allow: 
                <input type="checkbox" id="Targeting_CH" name="Targeting_CH" 

php if($p["CH"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="1">&nbsp;Switzerland
                &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="Targeting_AT" name="Targeting_AT" 

php if($p["AT"]=='1') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="1">&nbsp;Austria
```

---

This is what I get as result:

When it is the value 'DE' nothing appears below.

When it is the value 'USA' all (even the ones for 'DE') appears. Like this:

Also allow: `Canada ¦ United Kingdom ¦ Australia display:none;" id="de">` (>> last part shouldn't be displayed - 'means `display:none;" id="de">`')

Also allow: Switzerland Austria (>> this should actually displays on value 'DE')

Would very appreciate a solution that is helping me out.

Comment: `$p["country"]` has something to do with `<select name="countrycode"` ???

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is correct, check if your element's ID is not spelled wrong.